# Wix - Add row into custom collection when user is registered

Tags: javascript, velo

When a visitor create an account into my Wix website, i want to create default data into other custom collection and reference him.

For example : When John Doe is created. I create into Table A, two row with default data and reference him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create an [`onMemberCreated`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-members-backend/events/onmembercreated) event handler. Inside the event handler you can use the [`insert`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data/insert) function to add items to a database collection.

Comment: Yes thanks, i found this solution before. :)